Wanted to add lipstick like effect on lips using Vision and AVFoundation for camera
I wanted to add lipstick like effect on lips using CGMutable path. Detecting face landmarks using vision kit. Landmark.outer lips fill the whole lips, even opened mouth. i wanted to apply on the lips area only.
I have tried to play VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D.normalized path point but unable to achieve the result. Below is the code snippet.
let landmarkPath = CGMutablePath()
    let landmarkPathPoints = eye.normalizedPoints
        .map({ eyePoint in
            CGPoint(
                x: eyePoint.y * faceBoundingBox.height + faceBoundingBox.origin.x,
                y: eyePoint.x * faceBoundingBox.width + faceBoundingBox.origin.y
            )
        })

    
  landmarkPath.addLines(between: landmarkPathPoints)
    landmarkPath.closeSubpath()
    let landmarkLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    landmarkLayer.path = landmarkPath
    landmarkLayer.fillColor = nil
    landmarkLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    
    self.faceLayers.append(landmarkLayer)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(landmarkLayer)


"I have tried to play VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D.normalized path point but unable to achieve the result." How did your existing code fail to meet your requirements? What issue did you run into? You need to be more specific. Just saying "this didn't work" isn't helpful for people trying to answer the question or for future readers running into a similar issue.

I'm working on face beauty app. I have requirement to apply some effects on lips, nose, cheeks, eyes. For this purpose i explored the vision framework of apple. So right now i'm able to detect face landmarks, and applying some effects on that but in case of lips, effect is applying on whole lips including teeth area. What i'm expecting is it should put effect/masking color only on lips part, even mouth is open. I hope i conveys the point. Appreciate your help.
